# Is there a way to check if request history contains more than one item?

Tags: python, python-requests

Imagine this, a program that lists out all the redirects that a link has (i.e a grabify link.)

Now lets say you wanted to print "yes" if there was more than 1 link pasted, how can I do that?

This is the code that I have:

```py
import requests
import time

def nowdotheyes():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("...")
    time.sleep(3)
    responses = requests.get(link)
    for responses in responses.history:
        print(responses.url)
        if (responses.history > 1):
          print ("yes")
```

Comment: is responses.history a list? you should probably be able to use `len(responses.history) > 1` then

Comment: From the [requests docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/):  `The Response.history list contains the Response objects that were created in order to complete the request.` Use len() as mentioned by @Kim Kakan

Comment: @KimKakanAndersson Why would `len(responses.history) > 1` tell if something is a list or not?

Comment: It seems that the documentation says that it's always a list. 
Otherwise I guess you could use `if isinstance(responses.history, list)` if you don't trust the docs.
YOu can see an example here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-if-a-given-object-is-list-or-not/

Comment: Thanks Kim! I did try using lens but I didn't remove the for loop so /shrug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Is the finalized code, I provided a boolean and an int value for you to use in your program if needed. The "Icarly domain is the only one I know that redirects off hand"

```
import requests

def check(link):
    redirects = None
    responses = requests.get(link)
    print(responses.url)
    if len(responses.history) >= 1:
        redirects = True
        print ("Redirects More Than One Time")

    elif len(responses.history) <= 1:
        redirects = False
        print("Does Not Redirect More Than one time")

    total = int(len(responses.history))
    print(f"Total Number of Redirects {total}") # Just so you have the total number of redirects if you need it

    print(f"Redirect Status: {redirects}")  # A boolean that returns if it redirects



check(link="https://www.icarly.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kim Kakan Andersson, I realized the problem. I should have removed the for loop and added lens. Thanks everyone.